# Не получает извлечь результат запроса средствами PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Привет! есть такой sql запрос собранный для PDO execute() :

```
$sql ='SELECT
         posts.*,
         count(comments.id) AS comments
       FROM
         posts LEFT JOIN comments
       ON
         posts.id = comments.idpost
       WHERE
         posts.title LIKE ? OR
         posts.text LIKE ?
       GROUP BY
         posts.id
       ORDER BY id DESC
       LIMIT 0, 5';
$result = $this->pdo->prepare($sql);
$result->execute(array('%чтото%', '%чтото%'));
```

Код выполняется, но не возвращает результат, при этом напрямую в базе запрос с подставленными параметрами работает нормально. Почему это может происходить ?

Comment: а как Вы пытаетесь вывести результат? что у Вас после строки `$result->execute` ? и что возвращает `$result` ?

Answer (score 2):

Вот это странная конструкция (точнее странные ключи массива): `array(posts.title => '%чтото%', posts.text => '%чтото%')`, достаточно вот так: `array('%чтото%', '%чтото%')` - последовательность играет роль, данные будут подставляться по очередности вместо каждого из плесхолдеров.

Comment: Здесь вы правы, я просто неверно, описал здесь на сайте плейсхолдеры, в оригинале он  у меня без ключей, так что проблема остается все равно.

Comment: @E.Bud премер данных было бы неплохо увидить